# JSON rest service to HTML Table format

Tags: javascript, oracle

I have a rest service that returns the data below

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "empno":8240,
         "ename":null,
         "job":null,
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":null
      },
      {  
         "empno":8241,
         "ename":null,
         "job":null,
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":null
      },
      {  
         "empno":7839,
         "ename":"QUEEN",
         "job":"PRESIDENT",
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":10
      },
      {  
         "empno":7698,
         "ename":"BLAKE",
         "job":"MANAGER",
         "mgr":7839,
         "hiredate":"1981-05-01T00:00:00Z",
         "sal":2850,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":30
      },
      {  
         "empno":7566,
         "ename":"JONES",
         "job":"MANAGER",
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":20
      },
      {  
         "empno":7902,
         "ename":"FORDIAZ",
         "job":"ANALYST",
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":20
      },
      {  
         "empno":7844,
         "ename":"TURNER",
         "job":"SALESMAN",
         "mgr":7698,
         "hiredate":"1981-09-08T00:00:00Z",
         "sal":1500,
         "comm":0,
         "deptno":30
      },
      {  
         "empno":666,
         "ename":"Damian",
         "job":null,
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":null
      },
      {  
         "empno":8220,
         "ename":null,
         "job":null,
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":null
      },
      {  
         "empno":8221,
         "ename":null,
         "job":null,
         "mgr":null,
         "hiredate":null,
         "sal":null,
         "comm":null,
         "deptno":null
      }
   ],
   "hasMore":false,
   "limit":0,
   "offset":0,
   "count":10,
   "links":[  
      {  
         "rel":"self",
         "href":"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/oraclejet/emp/"
      },
      {  
         "rel":"edit",
         "href":"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/oraclejet/emp/"
      },
      {  
         "rel":"describedby",
         "href":"https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/oraclejet/metadata-catalog/emp/"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I just want to split this data and I need to show that as an HTML table format. How to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: please add what you have tried so far,

Comment: Actually i'm working using Oracle JET in which i need to show json as html table... https://jsfiddle.net/peppertech/wstnpgdL/  i have been following this jsfiddle link but for me it dosen't works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed by creating an `appendToTable()` function that will create a new row with the correct data and then append the newly created element to the table.

Then you can loop through all the data contained in the rest response and use the function to append one by one the rows to the table.

Here's a short snippet that gives a glimpse of how this can work:

```js
const data = {
  "items": [{
      "empno": 8240,
      "ename": null,
      "job": null,
      "mgr": null,
      "hiredate": null,
      "sal": null,
      "comm": null,
      "deptno": null
    },
    {
      "empno": 8241,
      "ename": null,
      "job": null,
      "mgr": null,
      "hiredate": null,
      "sal": null,
      "comm": null,
      "deptno": null
    },
    {
      "empno": 8221,
      "ename": null,
      "job": null,
      "mgr": null,
      "hiredate": null,
      "sal": null,
      "comm": null,
      "deptno": null
    }
  ]
}

let appendToTable = function(empno, ename, job) {
  let table = document.querySelector('.dataTable');
  let newRow = document.createElement('tr');
  newRow.innerHTML = `
    <th>${empno}</th>
    <th>${ename}</th>
    <th>${job}</th>
  `;
  
  table.appendChild(newRow)
  return newRow

}

for (let item of data.items) {
  appendToTable(item.empno, item.ename, item.job)
}
```

```html
<table class="dataTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Empno</th>
    <th>Ename</th>
    <th>Job</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works fine now in my table i need to add an extra column which shows image. How to achieve this using javascript?